# Parts of my mesh won't show any image texture when I go to material preview or rendered view

Tags: texturing, materials, uv-image-editor

So I'm using blender 2.8 and I'm texturing my mesh in texture paint mode. I've unwrapped it and applied the image to the unwrap. Ive linked the image texture node to the principled bsdf. (did everything right). I painted the whole body, but yet when I go to material preview or rendered view, the arms and legs won't show the texture. There's no lighting issues, but I did notice that in the uv image, when I go to the view tab and press show same material, the arms and legs vertexes are missing vs when I don't have show same material checked. I'm using the same image in texture paint and in my uv image editor tab though, so I'm soooo confused. Someone please help.